# with letters of word 'WHENCE' how many 3-letter password can be created

Tags: education

how many 3-letter passwords can be created with letters of word 'WHENCE'?

- 96
- 78
- 60
- 72

are options to answer

Comment: It is 72 but you should make an attempt  to figure out yourself why.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:**

Every letter place has 6 options. because same letter can repeat itself.